# How to edit a property in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model with an attribute that is connected to another model as follow:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  synced = models.OneToOneField('SyncedBook'
                               related_name='internal',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  # some more attributes here...

  @property
  def book_address(self)
    return self.synced.book_address
```

However, the `book_address` is a also a FK in the `SyncedBook` table as follow:

```
book_address = models.ForeignKey('Address', db_index=True, null=True, blank=True,
                                  related_name='address_book', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I don't know and understand how to be able to edit the `book_address` through the Django admin page in `class BookingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)`, even though I have read over the documentation. At first I have the attribute as `readonly`, but now I want to be able to edit it and save the new address from the `Address` table. Is there a way to make it happen through the `class BookingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)` and how? Any example and solution would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Model properties are typically used for presenting logically defined data for a particular model instance and not necessarily storing data on the model instance itself.

An example of when to use a model property is as follows:

```
# Defines a product instance
class Product(model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

# calculate profits on product
@property
def profit(self)
    p = self.price - self.cost
    return p
```

In your case, you are trying to actually be able to modify data against a related model instance within the django admin. To me this sounds like more specifically an Inline (click [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) for documentation)

So in your case, you would need to create something like the following to your admin.py file:

```
class SyncedBookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BookInline

@admin.Register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # all your model admin settings
    inlines = [SyncedBookInline]
```

---

Additional Info:
The Inline solution should still work for you. Please see the working code listed below:

## models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Hero(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class HeroAcquaintance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    hero = models.OneToOneField(Hero, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

## admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *


class HeroAcquaintanceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = HeroAcquaintance

@admin.register(Hero)
class HeroAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'name',
    )
    inlines = [HeroAcquaintanceInline]


@admin.register(HeroAcquaintance)
class HeroAcquaintanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'name',
    )
```

## Screenshot:

[image: working django admin inline for onetoonefield screenshot]

Comment: Sorry for the wrong description. The relationship is models.OneToOneField, but not FK. I edited back. But the Book table does have an id linked to the SyncedBook id. In that case, what should I do?

Comment: I got 'SyncedBook' has no ForeignKey to 'Book'.

Comment: Was the model originally set up as a Foreign Key then changed to OneToOne?

Comment: No, by your example, I would like to be edit it through HeroAcquaintanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

Comment: I ran into this same issue while testing at first. I solved it bey deleting my SQLite, migration files then redoing migrations.